# Are there other uses for the render tag in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is the <%= render "example" %> tag only for partial views or are there actually other uses for this tag?

Comment: JFYI, there's no such thing as "render tag". Nor  "link_to tag", etc.

Comment: Can you explain what, precisely, is unclear to you about the documentation of the `render` method? That way, the Rails developers can improve the documentation so that future programmers don't run into the same problem.

Comment: Sorry just started with Ruby a few weeks back, what would be the correct term for it? ^_^ @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Sorry, I actually haven't checked the documentation, I am just working on some worksheets the school gave. I will totally give it a look @JörgWMittag

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

> There are a variety of ways to customize the behavior of render. You can render the default view for a Rails template, or a specific template, or a file, or inline code, or nothing at all. You can render text, JSON, or XML. You can specify the content type or HTTP status of the rendered response as well.

Comment: Ah, but that's controller's `render`. Not the same thing as view's render.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Ugh! Ok. So, is [ActionView::Helpers::RenderingHelper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper/render) the correct reference? Or???

Comment: Yep, this one is better :)

Comment: Thanks, pal. Tough crowd around here.

Comment: Well, you know, nerds love nothing more than correcting other nerds :)